# iOS animate a row on tableview

Tags: objective-c

I'm new on iOS programming. My situation is that I try inserting a row into tableview, I've try the function insertRowsAtIndexPath:withRowAnimation but it's animation is so fast. 
How can I make it slower?

I've got some answers that iOS does NOT allow to adjust its speed, so it's necessary to do my own animation within a block when calls insertRowsAtIndexPath:withRowAnimation likes

insertRowsAtIndexPath:withRowAnimation:***^{.....}***

But what exactly must I do in the block? Could anybody show me, I just want to make the animation slower!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not method `insertRowsAtIndexPath:withRowAnimation:^{.....}` thus you have to either accept the fact the the animation is going to fast or write you own animation code. 
Which for `UITableView` will be vary hard to do.

Comment: How can I write my own animation code? Can I get the specified cell on the tableview, and then animate it. Can you clear it for me, I can't make it work.